# Excel macros won't run from shapes or buttons

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

Using Excel 365.

My workbook has macros which are linked to buttons or shapes on several worksheets.  The macros work if I run them from the Macros dialog, or the VBA editor, but when I press a button or shape, I get the message:

"Cannot run the macro <Filename!macroname>. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled."

I tried it with the "Enable all macros" setting, but that did not help.

The strange thing is, sometimes the button *do* work.  And on at least one occasion, when I closed and reopened it, they did.

Comment: In which module did you place the code for this strange macro?

Comment: Is the macro linked to the `on_click` event of the control?

Comment: These macros are in ordinary modules. The buttons are Form Controls, not ActiveX. They (and the shapes) are connected to the modules through "Assign Macro..." on the right-click menu.

Comment: I'm having the same issue suddenly. Which version of Microsoft Office are you using? I feel like it might have something to do with the most recent update.

Comment: I'm using Office 365, which is updated continuously

Answer (score 0):

I've found changing the Trust Centre Macro settings to accept Excel 4.0 macros gets past this problem.  But this is less than ideal. Hopefully someone has a better fix.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).