# EXCEL 2010 all macrobuttons stopped working "Cannot run the macro '*'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled."

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, macros, macro-button

My many macro buttons were all working perfectly.  Suddenly, a while back, they all stopped working, in any workbook, including Personal.xlsb.

All my macro buttons refer to macros in Personal.xlsb, which is open, and in the default XLSTART location.

They are all form controls, not ActiveX.

The links are correct, re-assigning the macros does not resolve the issue.

Macros still run fine from the view macros dialog box, and from VB editor.

Macros which have *not previously been assigned to a button* run correctly from a newly created macro button.

Any ideas why the old buttons are not working, and how to fix it?

I changed from Office 2007 to x64 MS Office 2010 professional, and from windows 8.1 to W10, I cannot be sure if the macro-buttons ever worked in this version, I think they may have.

I also used MSO 2013, 2016, and 365, but discontinued, 2010 is the default.  Could this have been a cause?

Repairing office, scannow and DISM did not fix it.

There is no option in my Trust center macro settings to accept 4.0 macros, as suggested at [Excel macros won't run from shapes or buttons](https://superuser.com/questions/1690117/excel-macros-wont-run-from-shapes-or-buttons). (My settings are in the pictures below, I am not sure if I need to "enable all macros" if trust the VBA box is ticked?)

[image: trust center macro settings]

ActiveX settings- safe mode is enabled? [They are not ActiveX buttons in any case).
[image: ActiveX settings- safe mode is enabled]

File block is excel 2-4, probably not relevant?
[image: excel file block, v2-4, prob not relevant]

Design mode is greyed out
[image: design mode is greyed out when form buttons in sheet]

Comment: Please check the Trusted Locations on Excel Options. Test the workbook, after saving it on one of that paths. Another thought: open Explorer.exe and right-click on the file and see if there is a "Security" Unblock button (in 'General' tab). If so, click on it to try unblock execution.

Comment: @ALeXceL
Trusted locations are fine, or the macros wouldn't be running?  As mentioned the macros are in Personal.  It is in the default folder XLSTART.  What file in Explorer?

Comment: XLSTART must be listed in Trusted Locations. The file: Personal.xlsb. It might be blocked, who knows. After all, this behavior of Excel/Windows is abnormal.

Comment: The macro "S___StylesSamples_ListAllInWorkbook_NewSheet" is explicitly calling 'Personal.xlsb (...)' Try copying this piece of code to a module in the caller workbook to test if it works fine.

Comment: ALeXceL
Thanks I had removed the offending "Personal.xlsb" code from the StyleSamples macro, but forgot to update the code pasted here (now removed, as it was not a cause of the macro-button issue).  Interestingly that code error caused the same message to appear during execution of the macro, so it is a referencing issue not a trust issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a duplication of the macro's containing filename, which happens ***after*** you assign the macro and close the dialog.  It looks like something has been corrupted in the referencing of all macros that were previously assigned to macro-buttons.

[image: excel macro-button duplicate filename added after assign. Assign Macro]

This is what should be shown in the dialog (it shows for macros which were not assigned before the issue arose):

[image: DUPL FINENAME IN SQUARE BRACKS NOT ADDED IN NEWLY ASSIGNED MACROS, THIS BUTTON WORKS!]

Changing the macro name in VB editor (I added _ at the end), then freshly assigning it in the button "assign macro" dialog resolves the issue.

**Note** that changing the macro name back to the original causes the problem to reappear, even it it is reassigned in the assign macro dialog, so all the macro-buttons have to be reassigned to a ***new*** name.

**Note also** that manually altering the name in the "assign macro" address box does not work.  You have to scroll down and click the macro name in the list.  Moving it to another module does not work either.

It does not seem to happen where a macro name has not previously been assigned to a button, which suggests that it is some referencing problem.

Comment: Any answer to fix the referencing problem itself would save a lot of manually changing macro-buttons!  I haven't tried restarting Excel before changing the filename back to see if that might correct it...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I added a trusted location c:\temp and copied my file to there.
And it worked.

- Fix Error

[image]